# how to get the clicked or selected text from the web pages using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gettext

how to get the clicked or selected  text from the web pages using javascript ??

How to get specific text like the mobile number or email

Comment: Please show us your html and your code. without it can be really hard to give you a good answer

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```js
const getSelectionText = () => {
  let text = "";

  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }

  return text;
}
```